# Telerik's WPF RadColorPicker NoColorText property not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

I was trying to use NoColorText property of the telerik's WPF RadColorPicker control. I was expecting it to show the mentioned text in this property if the Color not set or it is null.

Following is the XAML code

```
<telerik:RadColorPicker x:Name="MyColorPicker" NoColorText="Text for No color" SelectedColor="{Binding Path=MyColor}" Width="200" />
```

Am I missing something or this property is not meant for this purpose.

Comment: What is `MyColor`, does it have a value? Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadColorPicker_NoColorText.htm) for clues?

Comment: According to the documentation: `Use this property only if ShowEmptyColor is set to true.`  Give it a go.

Comment: MyColor is the property in the ViewModel. Yes, I read the documentation. It says 'Use this property only if ShowEmptyColor is set to true' as Andrew said. But this control doesn't have any such property, atleast for it's WPF controls.